# form textarea isset

Tags: php, html

This is php/html form textarea code

```
<textarea name="txtDispMsg" cols="1" rows="1"  value="<?php if(isset($disp_msg)){echo $disp_msg;} ?>" <?php if(isset($flag) && $flag == 4){echo "div style = 'border:2px solid red;'" . "/div";}?>></textarea>
```

here i m checking if user has entered the value in textarea it shall stay there whether there is any other error in form.. so the data in other fields in form stays there.. but not textarea. why?

Am i using wrong method of setting/fixing value to textarea? Though it works in the case of normal text fields

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Value is not an attribute of the Textarea tag in HTML syntax.  If you want to display content within the Textarea, you must place the content between opening and closing Textarea tags.  You are trying to set the content by declaring value="content" and instead you need to do the following:

```
<textarea name="fieldName" cols="15" rows="4">CONTENT GOES HERE</textarea>
```

SEE:  http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/textarea

---

If you want your values to not clear when you submit, then you must process them at the top of the page looking for some action, and then set the values of them in the form.

```
<?php

// check if values submitted to page and if not, set empty value
// add html escaping just in case
$field1 = (isset($_GET['field1'])) ? htmlspecialchars($_GET['field1']) : "";
$field2 = (isset($_GET['field2'])) ? htmlspecialchars($_GET['field2']) : "";
$field3 = (isset($_GET['field3'])) ? htmlspecialchars($_GET['field3']) : "";
$field4 = (isset($_GET['field4'])) ? htmlspecialchars($_GET['field4']) : "";

// toggle radio button if one was selected
$on = ($field4 == "1") ? "checked" : "";
$off = ($field4 == "0") ? "checked" : "";

?>

<html>
<head><title>Test Page</title></head>
<body>
<h1>Test Page</h1>
<form action="test.php" method="GET">
Field 1: <input type="text" name="field1" value="<?php echo $field1; ?>" /><br />
Field 2: <input type="text" name="field2" value="<?php echo $field2; ?>" /><br />
Field 3: <textarea name="field3" cols="15" rows="5"><?php echo $field3; ?></textarea><br />
Field 4: On <input type="radio" name="field4" value="1" <?php echo $on; ?> /> &nbsp; <input type="radio" name="field4" value="0" <?php echo $off; ?> /><br />
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Of course you can add your additional logic and styling but the main issue with your code was bad HTML syntax and textarea is different than other form tags and has no 'value' parameter.

Comment: my target is that the user entered content shall stay there if there is error in another field and php tells user to correct that.. but it shall not clear the entire form and user has to enter all values again.. got it?

Comment: See edit above.  It all depends on where you submit your form to but simple example submitting back to the same page assuming it was called test.php.  You check for form variables and if they exist populate PHP variables with them, otherwise set them as empty strings.  Then just populate the form values with those variables and they will either be empty or not.  You can add logic if not empty then add the red font color, etc. thereafter.

Comment: thanks a lot mike. ALso can u tell me how can i do the same for radio button??  means if user clicks on a radio button and if there is error somewhere else that radio button shall stay there..

Comment: I would likely do same as above but the value of radio would be 1 or 0 and if 1, then have another variable called $flag = "" or $flag = " checked".  Then just always display <input type="radio" name="field4" value="1" <?php echo $flag; ?> />  and at top of page if $_GET['field4'] isset, then $flag = " checked" otherwise "";

Comment: No worries.  Also added example of how to handle radio button in edited original answer just for others' benefit if they read this thread.

Answer (score 2):

value is not used in textarea , change

```
<textarea name="txtDispMsg" cols="1" rows="1"  value="<?php if(isset($disp_msg)){echo $disp_msg;} ?>" <?php if(isset($flag) && $flag == 4){echo "div style = 'border:2px solid red;'" . "/div";}?>></textarea>
```

to

```
<textarea name="txtDispMsg" cols="1" rows="1">
<?php if(isset($disp_msg)){echo $disp_msg;} elseif(isset($flag) && $flag == 4){echo "<div style='border:2px solid red;'></div>";} ?>
</textarea>
```

See: [textarea](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/HTML_Elements/textarea)

Comment: it does not solve the acutal problem.. i hope you understand the problem